# Is there anyway to suspend the notificationlistener in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there anyway to suspend the [notificationlistener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html). because I don't want to trigger this function.

I have to dothing in ScrollUpdateNotification . but when my press the button i want to pause the notificationlistener and stop doing thing in onNotification.